# How do I set the selected colour for ListPicker item

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, listpicker

Currently the selected item in a ListPicker is being set to the phone accent colour, how do I override this with a custom colour?

I know this will be done with a style but I am unsure what this should be...

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the `ListPicker.ExpansionMode`. If it's `ExpansionAllowed` - your style should be something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="toolkit:ListPickerItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 6"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ListPickerItem">
                <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                        Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <!-- Normal color -->
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                        Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <!-- Selected color -->
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <!-- Optionally - background selected color -->
                                    <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                        Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentControl
                        x:Name="ContentContainer"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, if it's `FullScreenOnly` - the only way is to modify the toolkit source code and build it with required changes. In my opinion, it isn't worth it.

Comment: thanks but how to i set this as the style property for a ListPicker

Comment: If you want to apply it to all `ListPicker` elements on the page - put it in page resources like here: `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage><phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>%YOUR_STYLE%</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources></phone:PhoneApplicationPage>`

Comment: I tried it out on completely clean page, everything works fine. I somewhere read, I don't remember where exactly, that there are some template differences in toolkit versions, `Padding` in particular. First, try 10 instead of 6. If that doesn't help - do you have the latest toolkit, [November](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888)? One more reason could be the custom `ItemTemplate`, try without it, if you have one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but having to use Feb'11 version of toolkit becuase of third party dependancy, I also read about the padding issue, looks like I'll give up trying to change it

Comment: Well, if it's important for the integrity of your design - you can always rebuild the Feb'11 toolkit with all necessary changes. In this case hard-code will be OK.